# Capitalize First Letter but not when number comes in first place in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-re, capitalize

> You are asked to ensure that the first and last names of people begin > with a capital letter in their passports. For example, **alison heck** > should be capitalised correctly as **Alison Heck**.
> **NOTE** In a word only the first character is capitalized. Example 12abc when capitalized remains 12abc.

One test case is failed i.e.
Input (stdin)

```
1 w 2 r 3g
```

Expected Output

```
1 W 2 R 3g
```

My Output

```
1 W 2 R 3G
```

### Please improve this code

```py
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


def solve(s):
    
    
    x = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ", s)
    a = x.title()
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    s = input()

    result = solve(s)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the proper formatting for your code snippets.

Comment: In your splits you can check with built-in Python functions if the first letter is not digit or lower case and only in these cases you can replace the first letter with the upper case letter. Hint: `isdigit`, `upper`, `replace` (this can be used with `1` as third parameter to only replace the first letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `split` the input on space and then use `capitalize`, which will convert the first character of each string to titlecase. Then you can `join` the words together again. For example:

```py
inp = '1 w 2 r 3g'
res = ' '.join(s.capitalize() for s in inp.split())
```

Output:

```
1 W 2 R 3g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple loop that capitalizes a character if preceded by a space.

```
x = re.sub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", " ", s)
a = x[0]
for i in range(1, len(x)):
    if x[i - 1] == " ":
        a = a + x[i].title()
    else:
        a = a + x[i]
return a
```

Output is:

```
1 W 2 R 3g
```

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you just `str.title()` this? There is no such thing as an uppercase number, so `”123abc”.title()` should produce your desired result still.

Comment: `'123abc'.title()` produces `123Abc`, which is *not* the desired result